# For calculating the limit $\lim_{x \to 0} x\cot(2x)$, why is it wrong to follow the second method?

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification

I'm preparing for my Graduate Admission Test, let's considering this limit:

$$
\lim_{x \to 0} x\cot(2x)
$$

The correct answer is :

$$
\lim_{x \to 0} x\cot(2x) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac {x}{\tan(2x)} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac {1}{2\sec^22x} = \frac {1}{2}
$$

But I'm doing like this:

$$
\lim_{x \to 0} x\cot(2x) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac {\cot(2x)}{\frac{1}{x}} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac {2\csc^2x}{\frac {1}{x^2}} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac {2x^2}{\sin^2x} = 2
$$

Because

$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {x}{\sin x} = 1  \Longrightarrow \lim_{x \to 0} \frac {2x^2}{\sin^2x} = 2
$$

So, what am I doing wrong? After thinking about it several times, it feels okay.

Comment: What happened to chain rule? $(\cot 2x)' = -2\csc^2 2x$, not $-2\csc^2 x$.

Comment: Thanks , I got it.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for @Ninad Munshi , I'm using the wrong chain rule.

Correct method is:

$$
\lim\limits_{x \to 0} x \cot\left( 2 x \right) = \lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\cot\left( 2 x \right)}{\frac{1}{x}} = \lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{2 \csc^{2}\left( 2 x \right)}{\frac {1}{x^2}} = \lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{2  x^{2}}{\sin^{2}\left( 2 x \right)} = \lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac {\left( 2  x \right)^{2}}{\sin^{2}\left( 2  x \right)} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, since $\sin(2x)\sim 2x$ when $x\to 0$, you may approach the proposed exercise as follows:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to 0}x\cot(2x) & = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x\cos(2x)}{\sin(2x)}\\\\
& = \lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{2x}{\sin(2x)}\right)\frac{\cos(2x)}{2}\\\\
& = \lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{2x}{2x}\right)\frac{\cos(2x)}{2}\\\\
& = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos(2x)}{2} = \frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: That’s the simplest solution I think, +1

Answer (score 0):

By Taylor's formula,
$$\frac{1}{\tan(2x)}=\frac{1}{2x+O(x^3)}$$
as $x\to0$. Multiplying by $x$ and taking the limit gives $1/2$.